# Ajax call from Yes No Dialog in Dojo

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, dojo

I have a requirement where I have to make a ajax call to a controller on click of the Yes button from a Dojo Dialog Box.
The dojo dialog box is cretaed in javascript and is called when a button in Jsp is clicked.

Dojo Dialog Box Code:

```
function launchYesNoDialog(message,action) {
    require(["dijit/Dialog", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog){
        yesNoDialog = new Dialog({
            title: "Warning",
            content: message+'<BR><BR><BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
            ' <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="yesButton">Yes</button>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
            '<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="noButton" data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){yesNoDialog.hide();}">No</button>'
        });
    });
    yesNoDialog.show();
}
```

The Jsp Button code from where the dojo dialog is getting called.

```
<button type="button" id="removeCustomerButton"
                                 style="float: left;"
                                disabled="disabled" onclick="launchYesNoDialog(confirmMessage,'Remove');">
                                <SPAN class=grey><EM><s:message
                                            code="customer.removeCustomer" text="" /></EM></SPAN>
                            </button>
```

And the Ajax code in javascript where the ajax functionlity is present is below:

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/json", "dojo/on", "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(xhr, dom, domConst, JSON, on, lang){
          on(document.getElementById("yesButton"), "click", function(){
              var val = selectedId;
              if(lang.trim(val).length == 0){
                  return;
              }
              waitingForResponse();
            xhr("relationship/deleteCustomer/"+val, {
              handleAs: "json"
            }).then(function(data){
                waitingEnd();
                buildDataGrid("relationGrid", data, null, 0, 'A');
            },  function(err){
                waitingEnd();
                /*if(err.response.text != null && err.response.text.indexOf("j_username") > -1){
                    launchSessionTimeout();
                } else {
                    alert("Error: " + err.response.text);
                }*/
            });
    });
});
```

Now when the page is loaded I am getting a javascript which says "Null Object error" and this is coming becasue of this below line  on i suppose.

> (document.getElementById("yesButton"), "click", function()

Before the Yes Button is rendered in DOM javascript is trying to find it.
Could any one please provide any solution ?

Comment: If I do this dialog box creation in jsp and make a div of type dojo dialog then I can resolve this issue. But I want to achive this using the current approach. FYI I am using Dojo 1.9.. so cannt use Dojo Confirm Dialog box also as that is present in 1.10 library I guess

Answer (score 1):

when you are using a dijit widget then you should try to get a reference of the dijit object using `dijit/registry` module.

Also you need to parse the html contents in the dialog to make the yes/no buttons into dijits.

```
function launchYesNoDialog(message,action) {
    require(["dijit/Dialog", "dojo/parse", "dojo/domReady!"], function(parse, Dialog){
        yesNoDialog = new Dialog({
            title: "Warning",
            content: message+'<BR><BR><BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
            ' <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="yesButton">Yes</button>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
            '<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="noButton" data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){yesNoDialog.hide();}">No</button>'
        });
        parser.parse(yesNoDialog.content);
    });

    yesNoDialog.show();
}
```

Add the `dijit/registry` module to the require call.

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/json", "dojo/on", "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/registry", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(xhr, dom, domConst, JSON, on, registry, lang){
          //on(document.getElementById("yesButton"), "click", function(){
          registry.byId("yesButton").on("click", function(){
          ....
```

If the above still does not work than you can create you own confirmation dialog widget with the help of this example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/wkydY/).